# Connecting to Azure Devops RestAPI - Returns html, Status Code 203

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to connect to my Azure DevOps Rest API to produce some summary information regarding version numbers.  I am running into an issue:

Here is my script:

```
$PAT = "xxxxredactedxxxxx"
$OrgName = "mycompany-devops"
$ProjectName = "MyCompany Infrastructure As Code"
$ApiVersion = "6.0"

# Get a list of all services in the organization
$services = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/distributedtask/serviceendpoints?api-version=$ApiVersion" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

# Loop through each service and get its version
foreach ($service in $services.value) {
    $serviceType = $service.type
    $serviceUrl = $service.url
    $serviceId = $service.id
    $serviceName = $service.name
    
    # Get the version of the service
    $serviceVersion = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$serviceUrl?api-version=$ApiVersion" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}
    
    # Print the service type, name, and version
    Write-Output "${serviceType}: $serviceName version $($serviceVersion.properties.version)"
}

# Get the version of the Azure DevOps Server
$azureDevOpsServerVersion = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/$ProjectName/_apis/distributedtask/server?api-version=$ApiVersion" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

# Print the Azure DevOps Server version
Write-Output "Azure DevOps Server version $($azureDevOpsServerVersion.properties.version)"
```

The PAT doesn't seem to be working correctly.  That is most likely why I am seeing the 203 status.
Can you take a look at this script and let me know what is causing this to happen?  Its been driving me nuts!

I am getting status 203 and a bunch of HTML.

Comment: Status 203 means a proxy has modified the results.

Comment: There is no proxy.

Comment: You can search the web and see that status code 203 is for a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to use your code and received the same error code as yours:-***

[image]

The Rest API endpoints that you're using are incorrect, I tried the below API for Azure DevOps service endpoint and it worked:-

**Rest API:-**

> I used the below API from this MS Document - [Endpoints - Get Service
> Endpoints - REST API (Azure DevOps Service Endpoint) | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get-service-endpoints?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)
>
> ```http
> https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/serviceendpoint/types?api-version=6.0-preview.1
> ```

**Code:-**

```
$PAT = "xxxxxxxh6vllte3enjw5fkj2rdjdft5agoyhf7wlqrona"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "6.0"

$services = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/serviceendpoint/types?api-version=6.0-preview.1" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

$services.value
# Loop through each service and get its version
```

**Output:-**

[image]

For Distributed task use the Rest API below:-

> **Rest API:-**
>
> I used below API from this MS document - [Agents - Get - REST API
> (Azure DevOps Distributed Task) | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

```http
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=7.0
```

**Code:-**

```
$PAT = "xxxxxxl6h6vllte3enjw5fkj2rdjdft5agoyhf7wlqrona"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "6.0"
$services= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/distributedtask/pools/9/agents/8?api-version=6.0" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}
$services.value
```

List Distributed task:-

> I used below API from this MS document:- [Agents - List - REST API
> (Azure DevOps Distributed Task) | Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/agents/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)
>
> **API:-**
>
> ```http
> https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/pools/9/agents?api-version=7.0
> ```

**Code:-**

```
$PAT = "xxxxxxx6h6vllte3enjw5fkj2rdjdft5agoyhf7wlqrona"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "6.0"
$azureDevOpsServerVersion = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/_apis/distributedtask/pools/9/agents?api-version=7.0" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}
$azureDevOpsServerVersion.value
# Loop through each service and get its version
```

**Output:-**

[image]